# Adding a 120v circuit off 240v spa wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, subpanel

I have a hot tub installed with 4-wire 50 amp service, with the GFCI 2-pole breaker at the main panel, and a simple non-fused pull disconnect switch subpanel near the hot tub.

I want to split off a 120v line with a 10 amp breaker and receptacle at the subpanel for LED lighting. Is this possible without running more wire from the main panel? Can a branch circuit be placed downline from the GFCI?

Comment: A non-fused pull disconnect switch is not a subpanel.  The entire run from the main panel to the hot tub is the branch circuit.  There are no feeders involved.  If  you changed the "not subpanel" to an "actual subpanel" that would change the picture.  The GFCI in the main can protect all.

Comment: How many wires are run from the main panel to/through the disconnect?

Comment: Voltages in the U.S. have been 120/240 since the post-war era. Are you somewhere else?

Comment: All four wires from the main panel run through the disconnect box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you come off the 50 amp feed for LED lights, yes. But what you have now is a non fusible disconnect, not a sub panel that can add another breaker for your LED lights. You can not just stick a 15 amp wire for lights under the 50 amp terminal and run your lights. (the wire would melt long before the breaker trips if there was an issue). You will need to take the 50 amp wire into a sub panel instead of the disconnect and then have 2 separate breakers for the hot tub and the lights that will be added.

It depends on your situation whether that is easier to do then running a new 15 amp line for your lights from the existing panel or even coming off another 15 amp circuit elsewhere in the house.

Comment: Thanks, Keith. Given that the breaker (it's GFCI) is currently in the main panel, do I replace that with a non-GFCI breaker, moving the existing GFCI breaker into a new subpanel with a separate 110V breaker?

I assume I would purchase a new box like this: https://www.spadepot.com/MW-Spa-GFCI-Load-CenterDisconnect-240V-up-to-50A-P10588C193.aspx

Comment: A box like what you have linked there would work great. Then just add a 15 amp breaker for your lights and your good to go. You would not need to have another gfi breaker in the panel but I would leave it there as that will also protect the outdoor lights and keep that safe as well. Any receptacle then that is on your lighting circuit would be already GFI protected then as well. It's a little strange to do it that way but saves you from having to buy another breaker as a gfi breaker comes with the link you sent.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense to leave the GFCI in the main panel. Thanks for your help!!